# C++ Linking static library (assimp)

Tags: c++

I'm having trouble understanding how libraries work in C++.
Each library seems to have radically different ways to include it in a project.

I'm using CLION, which uses CMake. I understand the difference between (dynamic vs static vs header-only libraries)

I want to integrate `[assimp][1]` into my project. Here's what I'm doing:

**1 -  I've downloaded a precompiled version of assimp for my system using [homebrew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/assimp): `brew install assimp`**

**2 - This created a folder `/usr/local/Cellar/assimp/5.0.1` which contains `/include` `/bin` `/libs`**

My understanding is as follows (please correct me if I'm wrong)

```
`/include`: contains the header files
`/libs`: contains the dynamic library files
`/bin`: contains the compiled static library
```

**3 - I want to link statically, so I copied the folders `/include` and `/bin` into my project. Placed them inside `/myproject/vendor/assimp`**

4 - **Modified my CMakeList.txt file so it looks like:**

```
project(game)

file(GLOB src ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.cpp)
add_library(game ${src})

target_include_directories(game PUBLIC
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/vendor/assimp/include/)

target_link_libraries(game PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/vendor/assimp/bin/assimp)
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/Debug/sandbox
ld: can't link with a main executable file '../../engine/vendor/assimp/bin/assimp' for architecture x86_64
```

Comment: `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/vendor/assimp/bin/assimp` is that an existing library file? Does it have a `.a` or `.so` extension?

Comment: yes, the folder contains a `assimp` executable file. I was expecting a `.a`... but I guess the extension was omited?

Comment: The `file` command at the terminal should tell you what type of file it is (well it does on linux)

Comment: Thanks! it outputted `assimp: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64`. I'm even more confused now. Why does a library have an executable target

Comment: On #2, that could be right, but it isn't a requirement. What files exist in those folders, particularly the `libs` and `bin`? A more typical convention would be to put static and dynamic libraries in the `libs` directory and executables in `bin`. On #3, I don't think you need to copy the files into your project. Why do you feel this is needed? On #4, it depends on the layout of your files on disk. More typical usage is to separate the dir and lib, so you'd use `target_link_directories()` for the former (adding the folders in `/usr/...`) and `target_link_libraries()` for the latter.

Comment: @metal `I don't think you need to copy the files into your project. Why do you feel this is needed?` I want to use the library, and would like other people to have it when cloning my repo (instead of having to fetch each library independently)